# How to exclude specific keywords from UrlMapping in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

I use the following url mapping in Grails:

```
"/$id"{
  controller = "user"
  action = "show"
}
```

to map urls like **mydomain.com/someusername**

How do I attach constrains to the url mapping to exclude keywords like "login", "logout",...

I.e., 
mydomain.com/someusername should route to mydomain.com/user/show/someusername,
mydomain.com/login should not route to mydomain.com/user/show/login.

Comment: What did you mean by *user/show/login*? Is `login` an action?

Comment: mydomain.com/someusername should route to mydomain.com/user/show/someusername,
mydomain.com/login should not route to mydomain.com/user/show/login.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use contrainsts for this mapping:

```
"/$id"{
  controller = "user"
  action = "show"
  constraints {
    //add a validator for $id from url mapping
    id(validator: {
        return !(it in ['login', 'logout'])
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [filter](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html), and redirect from it.

```
class UrlMappingFilters {
    def filters = {
        filterUrlKeywords(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            def keywords = ['login', 'logout']
            before = {
                if (params.id in keywords) {
                    // redirect to start, or render error...
                    redirect(uri: '/')
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make it specific to a controller or action, use its name instead of the `'*'`.

Read more:

- [Official docs on Grails filters](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters)
- [Reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this type of thing for REST based endpoints numerous times, and Grails is smart enough to figure out what you want.  **Note that ordering in the UrlMappings file may be important**.

For example, you can define this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/login" { controller: 'auth', action: 'login' }
        "/logout" { controller: 'auth', action: 'logout' }
        "/$id" { controller: 'user', action: 'view' }
    }
}
```

Then when you hit "/login" you will go in the auth:login method, but when you hit "/userid" you will be sent to user:view:userid as expected.