# How to make URL Mappings for both REST and browser based interactions

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I want the following functions from my controller and each of these are supported by matching REST:

- Create a color
- Fetch a particular color based on id
- Fetch all colors

I've got the following URL scheme:

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/color"(controller: "color", parseRequest: true) {
       action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"]
    }
    "/color/$id" (resource: "color")
```

The above does not work well for both REST and browser based interactions.

`http://localhost:8080/color/create` ends up going to the `show` action instead. I expect it to go to `create` action which shows the form.

If I remove the last mapping `"/color/$id" (resource: "color")` then it works fine however, then the URL `http://localhost:8080/color/7` breaks

**Question**

What is a right way of making all these URLs work consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constraint to the `urlMapping` plus make sure the default mapping is available.

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}

"/user/$id" (resource: "user"){
    constraints {
        id validator: {
            !(it in ['create', 'otherAction'])
        }
    }
}
```

Co-incidentally, a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17011442/2051952).